# Error installing OpenVPN - Files missing

Tags: raspbian

I am building Raspberry Pi B+ VPN using OpenVPN. Following this tutorial http://readwrite.com/2014/04/10/raspberry-pi-vpn-tutorial-server-secure-web-browsing and this tutorial http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-33548728 I need to do

```
cp -r /usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/easy-rsa/2.0 /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa
```

However, when I run this I get:

> cp: cannot stat ‘/usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/easy-rsa/2.0’: No such file or directory

I have done:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install openvpn
```

Everything is up to date. Any thoughts?

Comment: Well, is the folder there? What do you get from: `ls /usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/easy-rsa/`

Comment: I get the message:"No such file or directory"". Thank you for your speedy help, I am really unsure what to do here.

Comment: work your way upwards, is there anything if you do `ls /usr/share/doc/openvpn/`?

Comment: Yes, I have that file, I see several words of red and white and blue: in blue, examples; in red, COPYING.gz and others; in white, PORTS, README, and others. Many thanks, what next?

Comment: OK, so that means that you have a folder called `/usr/share/doc/openvpn/` so probably your command `sudo apt-get install openvpn` did not failed completely. The command `ls` is used to list files and folders. You do have a `examples` folder. What's in there? What do you get if you type `ls /usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples` ?

Comment: I see: (code) sample-config-files, sample-keys, and sample-scripts (/code), thanks. (I have done some command line practice but not much your are very helpful here.)

Comment: It should have also a easy-rsa folder. What I would suggest is remove openvms and install again. To remove `sudo apt-get remove openvms`. To install again `sudo apt-get install openvms`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30383/discussion-between-mircea-baja-and-thomas-shera).

Comment: I meant `openvpn` in the above message

Answer (score 12):

You are probably following instructions for Debian Wheezy while running Jessie.

On Jessie and above:

1. `apt-get install easy-rsa`
2. `cp -R /usr/share/easy-rsa/* /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/`

I found that (1) is not necessary since it is now a dependency of OpenVPN.

See https://wiki.debian.org/OpenVPN#OpenVPN_Overview

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem today while setting up my own VPN. I finally got it working by following the instructions on [this site](http://www.slsmk.com/getting-started-with-openvpn/installing-openvpn-on-ubuntu-server-12-04-or-14-04-using-tun/).
Basically, the only two commands I needed were:

```
sudo apt-get install easy-rsa
sudo make-cadir /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa
```

After that, all the required folders and files were right where the tutorial told me.

I know, the question is not the newest, but maybe I could help you or others that have trouble setting up OpenVPN, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
cp -r /usr/share/easy-rsa /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa
```

They changed the locations with upgrades.

Comment: this should be marked as the correct answer

Answer (score -2):

I had the exact same problem.  If you grep for easy-rsa, you'll find a .deb package in /var/cache/apt/archives.  Try manually installing it with 
    dpkg -i /path/to/package.

Comment: Why did this get a thumbs down, does it not work? Will try ASAP.

Comment: Not sure. This was the only way I found to solve this issue. Did it work out @ThomasShera?

Comment: I unfortunately haven't had chance to test this yet, although I later diagnosed the problem was a spotty Ethernet connection. Thanks again for the help, really appreciate it.